# Mapping local history

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, google

I have been working almost half a year now trying to create a modern digital map of the local towns protected historical silver mines. The only GOOD map over the mines dates back to 1794. A new map was started on in 1920, but never finished.

This is a non-commercial hobby project, but the national Mining Museum of Norway supports me with access to historical maps and other available sources.
Although I have no experience contributing to maps, drawing the map is not a problem. I have found the Go Maps ipad app for openstreetmap (OSM) to be an exellent work tool with a digital terrain model (Lidar?) as background when I combine it with surveys.

My problem is that if I want to play by the rules using 100% correct tagging, what I draw will never be visible on OSM. 
By cheating a little with the tags, what I have drawn so far is visible on Mapnik and is being used by people visiting the area. On my recommendation they are using an app like Galileo Offline Maps to tell them where they are and where to find f.ex. the adit of a mine.
What I miss the most in Galileo is the option to click on an object on the map and then open a panel showing the existing tags incl. links to web pages containing more info about the selected object.

I can easily extract what I draw from OSM and store on my computer as KML or GeoJSON data. It also seems I could be able to achieve what I am describing above with a Google MyMaps layer - but it would be nice to be able to do this independently of a commercial company. 
I believe I am searching for an app where a “correctly” OSM map will be displayed with all details - or for a tool to create something myself without any knowledge except a bit of basic programming back in the 1990s.
Does eventually someone here know people who write such apps and/or render OSM Maps just for the fun if it?

Stein

Comment: Thanks. Are these complicated to use? Could you please give me some links?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). They can render your selfmade and self-hosted stuff on top of Openstreetmap or other basemaps, without any confusion with the OSM database. Google might ask you for a paid license, OSM/OpenLayers/Leaflet is free.

If you need to prepare and style your data first, you might start of offline with [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and use the qgis2web plugin to create a web map based on OpenLayers or Leaflet.

You may visit my [hobby project](http://karte.nrwbahnarchiv.bplaced.net/) to see what you can get out of that combination.

Or try [uMAP](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/UMap).